# How can I update lookup fields in a row with randomly chosen rows from the related table in access SQL?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table with 5 fields that are all the same.  They each can hold a reference to a row from another table with relationships.  I want to update all  of these fields at the same time on a row, but with a randomly selected row from the table for each field (with no duplicates).  I am not sure how in access SQL you can update a lookup/relationship field like this.  Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is that you can't, not as it appears you would like to anyway. The closest thing possible would be to create an Insert query with parameters, and then feed in your 5 values using VBA. Since you will have to use VBA anyway, you may as well go the whole hog and conduct the entire process with Recordsets.

But that's not the fiddly part, (relatively speaking) selecting your source values is. What you will need to do is open a Recordset on your source table, and hook it up to your random-no-duplicates logic in order to select your 5 record references, then you open up a Recordset on your destination table, and drop them in the appropriate fields.

This tutorial will get you started on Recordsets: http://www.utteraccess.com/wiki/index.php/Recordsets_for_Beginners